# ionic 3 : Googleplus not recognised as provider in app.module.ts

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, google-plus

I am trying to build my ionic project for production, by using the following command.
**ionic cordova build android --prod --release**, but i always have this error :
**JavaScript heap out of memory**, so i looked on the web and i tried the following solution : the adding of **node --max_old_space_size=4096** in my ionic.cmd file, but it did not worked. As i use firebase, i tried to downgrade firebase using this command :

```
npm install --save firebase@4.x
```

So now the **GooglePlus class of googleplus plugin** of my project is not recognised as an ionic  provider. Here are the commands i used to install it :

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googleplus --save --variable REVERSED_CLIENT_ID=MY_REVERSE_CLIENT_ID

npm install --save @ionic-native/google-plus
```

When i am trying to import the **GooglePlus** class in my app.modules.ts, in the providers section, it is not recognised. I tried to uninstall and re-install everything but it does not work.

```
{


"name": "app name",
  "version": "2.0.1",
  "author": "auhtors name",
  "homepage": "website url",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.10",
    "@ionic-native/admob-free": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/admob-pro": "^4.19.0",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "^4.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/barcode-scanner": "^4.19.0",
    "@ionic-native/browser-tab": "^4.19.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/facebook": "^4.19.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^4.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/firebase": "^4.13.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-plus": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/instagram": "^4.19.0",
    "@ionic-native/local-notifications": "^4.13.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/open-native-settings": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/youtube-video-player": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "angular-pipes": "^8.0.0",
    "angularfire2": "^5.1.1",
    "cordova-admob-sdk": "^0.17.0",
    "cordova-android": "^7.1.4",
    "cordova-instagram-plugin": "^0.5.7",
    "cordova-ios": "^4.5.5",
    "cordova-open-native-settings": "^1.5.2",
    "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "^1.7.2",
    "cordova-plugin-admob-free": "^0.17.4",
    "cordova-plugin-admobpro": "^2.37.1",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-badge": "^0.8.7",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-document-viewer": "^0.9.10",
    "cordova-plugin-extension": "^1.5.4",
    "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^3.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^3.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-local-notification": "^0.9.0-beta.2",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^5.4.4",
    "cordova-plugin-youtube-video-player": "^1.0.6",
    "cordova-promise-polyfill": "0.0.2",
    "cordova-universal-clipboard": "git+https://github.com/Visigo/CordovaClipboard.git",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "firebase": "^5.8.2",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionic-img-viewer": "^2.9.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^5.1.0",
    "ng2-simple-timer": "^1.3.3",
    "ngx-moment": "^3.1.0",
    "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": "^8.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.11",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.1",
    "@ionic/lab": "1.0.18",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
  },
  "description": "app description",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-admob-free": {},
      "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "24.1.1+"
      },
      "cordova-instagram-plugin": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
      "cordova-open-native-settings": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-youtube-video-player": {},
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-document-viewer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-local-notification": {},
      "cordova-plugin-firebase": {},
      "cordova-universal-clipboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-admobpro": {
        "PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION": "16.0.0"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-facebook4": {
        "APP_ID": "appid",
        "APP_NAME": "237actu",
        "FACEBOOK_HYBRID_APP_EVENTS": "false",
        "FACEBOOK_ANDROID_SDK_VERSION": "4.38.1"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-googleplus": {
        "REVERSED_CLIENT_ID": "app reverse client id"
      }
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "ios"
    ]
  }
}
```

And here is an excerpt the content of the app.module.ts file

```
import { GooglePlus } from '@ionic-native/google-plus';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
  ],
  imports: [
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(config),
    BrowserModule,
    PdfViewerModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicImageViewerModule,
    NgPipesModule,
    MomentModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
  ],
  providers: [
    AngularFireAuth,
    GooglePlus,
    UserAuthService,
    Facebook,
    RestClientService,
    AdmobFreeService,
    StatusBar,
    UserserviceProvider,
    SplashScreen,
    LocalNotifications,
    AdMobFree,
    SocialSharing,
    Instagram,
    Network,
    Camera,
    FileTransfer,
    File,
    OpenNativeSettings,
    SimpleTimer,
    InAppBrowser,
    YoutubeVideoPlayer,
    BarcodeScanner,
    AppVersion,
    Firebase,
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler }
  ]
})
```

Any help ?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `ngx` like this:

```
import { GooglePlus } from '@ionic-native/google-plus/ngx';
```

> Import the plugin in a @NgModule and add it to the list of Providers.
>   For Angular, the import path should end with /ngx. Angular's change
>   detection is automatically handled. - https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/

Comment: still not working